# External force and centre of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames

I’ve read that linear momentum of a system will be constant when there is no external force on the system. Thus, the velocity of the centre of mass will be the same. Thus, this means that the position on COM of the system is not constant, but instead moves with a constant velocity.

Then, in the link given below, gravity, an external force is acting on the system in the y-direction. Thus, there is no force on the x-direction and thus, the velocity of the x-com is constant. Now, as the initial velocity of the x-com was zero, the final velocity of the x-com will also be zero and thus the position of x-coordinate of the com does not change. This realisation is being exploited to solve the question.

Is my understanding correct?

[The question being referenced](https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/a-bead-can-slide-on-a-smooth-straight-wire-and-a-class-11-physics-cbse-5f6437ec2ac31d634790bac5)

Comment: Relevant meta post about ["check my understanding" questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13109/179151)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thus, this means that the position on COM of the system is not constant, but instead moves with a constant velocity.

That depends on whether there was an initial momentum, an initial speed. As you say yourself in the next paragraph, if the initial speed (of the centre-of-mass) is zero, then it *remains* zero if there are no external forces acting. Your understanding seems correct.